# Simple_form doesn't load collection after render error_message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, simple-form

In my create user view

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>

<%= f.input :size, :collection => @plan, :label_method => :details, 
:value_method =>:name,:include_blank => false %>
```

Collection/list loads fine. If a user inputs the wrong value and my the page reloads with the error notification, the :size field reloads as a numeric input field and not with my collection/list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your controller is still assigning @plan when an error occurs? You can confirm that by adding the following to your view to dump the @plan value:

```
<%= debug(@plan) %>
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, After my else in my controller I had to assign @plan again.